# Assign an observable to an array in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to initialize an array from an observable. However I get an compilation error saying:

[image]

Component:

```
export class LeaderBoardComponent implements OnInit {
    leaderBoardTableData: Array<LeaderBoardModel>;
    constructor(private appStore: Store<AppStore>,

        private leaderBoardService: LeaderBoardService) {
        this.leaderBoardService.getLeaderBoard()
            .skipWhile((data) => { return _.isEmpty(data) })
            .subscribe((data) => {
                if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
                    this.leaderBoardTableData = this.leaderBoardService.getLeaderBoard();
                }
            });
    }
```

Service:

```
 getLeaderBoard(): Observable<LeaderBoardModel> {
        return this.httpUtil.get(this.appConstants.END_POINT_LEADERBOARD)
            .map(response => <LeaderBoardModel>response.json());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLeaderBoard()` method returns an observable of a single `LeaderBoardModel` element. So upon subscription you have to push the subscribed value (which is `data`) to your `leaderBoardTableData` in the component.

I think it should be:

```
.subscribe((data) => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
        this.leaderBoardTableData = [data];
        // or `this.leaderBoardTableData.push(data);` , you have to make sure that `leaderBoardTableData` is already instantiated though
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe the `this.leaderBoardService.getLeaderBoard()` because you cannot assign an Observable to an array.

So do this in your code:

```
this.leaderBoardService.getLeaderBoard().subscribe(data => {
    this.leaderBoardTableData = data;
});
```

If you wanted `leaderBoardTableData` to be equal to an observable so that your code did not have to change, you could just change the type definition from:

```
leaderBoardTableData: Array<LeaderBoardModel>;
```

To:

```
leaderBoardTableData: Observable<LeaderBoardModel>;
```

Also be cognizant of the fact that you have a generic `Array` type, which means the return value of your observable must also be a generic `Array` type or you will get a similar type checking error from the compiler.